# Shiny: Increase highchart size on button click

Tags: r, highcharts, shiny, rcharts

I want to increase the size of highchart on clicking the zoom button. I tried using the code below to increase the size but so far I have not been able to achieve what I want to do. I actually wanted the highchart to expand and occupy the full page on clicking the zoom button. I have written the following code so far but it does not seem to work. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
require(shiny)
require(rCharts)

ui <- fluidPage(


  tags$script('Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler("ZoomPlot", function(variableName){
              document.getElementById(variableName).style.height = "1000px";
              });
              '),

  headerPanel("Test app"),
  actionButton("test", "Zoom"),

  div(class = "chart-container",  showOutput("viz", "highcharts"))
)



server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  output$viz <- renderChart2({
    a <- highchartPlot(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, data=iris)
    a
  })

  observeEvent(input$test,{
    session$sendCustomMessage(type = 'ZoomPlot', message = "viz")
  })
})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using only server side like

```
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  hh=reactive({
    if(input$test>0 ) {1000}else{400}
   })
  output$viz <- renderChart2({
    a <- highchartPlot(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, data=iris)
    a$set(height = hh()
          )
    a
  })

})
```